# Designing probability distribution function with given independencies

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I wanto construct a probability distribution on three binary valued ($yes, no$) random variables (say $P(X_1, X_2, X_3)$);

The independencies that P has to hold are  $X_1 \perp X_2, X_1 \perp X_3, X_3 \perp X_2$ but it should not follow $X_1,X_2 \perp X_3$;

I am successful in preserving the first three dependencies by assigning $P(X_i = yes) = 0.5$ for $1 \le i \le 3$

Using those values, I can calculate $P(X_i,X_j) = 0.25$ for $i \ne j$ and $P(X_1, X_2, X_3) = 0.125$, which satisfies unwanted independence.

Now, the first three properties hold. But it automatically holds unwanted independence $X_1, X_2 \perp X_3$ also.

How to develop distribution that satisfies pairwise independecies but not unwanted one?

Comment: To clarify: you do not want $(X_1,X_2)$ (as a pair) to be independent of $X_3$? If so, take $X_1,X_2$ to be independent Bernoulli random variables with parameter $1/2$, and $X_3 = X_1+X_2 \mod 2$.

Comment: @ClementC. Yeah, exactly. Both as a pair has to be independent with $X_3$

Comment: See my (updated) comment.

Comment: If $X_3 = X_1+X_2 \mod 2$, Then $P(X_3 =yes) = ?$

Comment: One half. They are all Bernoullis with parameter $1/2$.

Comment: @ClementC.: I think that comment should be an answer (to prevent this question from sitting around unanswered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_1,X_2$ be i.i.d. random variables following a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $1/2$, and let $X_3$ be their $\textsf{XOR}$:
$$
X_3 \stackrel{\rm def}{=} X_1\oplus X_2 = X_1+X_2\bmod 2\,.
$$
Then it is easy to see that $X_i\perp X_j$ for every $i\neq j$ (pairwise independence), that $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are identically distributed (all Bernoulli $1/2$); *but* of course $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are not jointly independent.

Comment: According to the definition of $X_3$, we can observe that it is satisfying all properties, but my doubt is, the probability distribution is still satisfying $P(X_1,X_2,X_3) = P(X_1, X_2) P(X_3)$ for all possible assignments of $X_1, X_2, X_3$, then how can we say that $X_3$ is independent of $X_1,X_2$ (Jointly)?

Comment: The probability distribution does **not** satisfy this.$\mathbb{P}\{X_1=1,X_2=1,X_3=1\}=0$ while $\mathbb{P}\{X_1=1,X_2=1\}=1/4$ and $\mathbb{P}\{X_3=1\}=1/2$ for instance... @hanugm

Comment: https://ibb.co/dsVDdz

Is it the distribution corresponding to it?

Comment: @hanugm yes, it is.